# Why is "buena" in different places depending on its use?

Tags: gramática, orden-de-palabras

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Significance of adjective placement](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/328/significance-of-adjective-placement)

In these phrases below, why is the word "buena" in different places?

> Are there good things? => ¿Hay cosas buenas?
>
> Are there good beers? => ¿Hay buena cerveza?

Answer (score 3):

You can translate them also like this:

> Are there good things? => ¿Hay buenas cosas?
>
> Are there good beers? => ¿Hay buena cerveza?

That way, "buena" is on the same place. :)

Note; however, that colors (red, white, etc.) *usually* go after the noun; for example:

> Casa Blanca , pelo rojo, etc.

Colors preceding the noun are mostly used in literature (poetry(?)) but it's very uncommon on spoken Spanish:

> Tu rojo pelo, tu fea cara, tus blancas manos (if you are a native Spanish speaker and you speak like this, people will likely think that you are a weirdo).

Also note that depending on whether the adjective preceeds the noun or not, the meaning could be quite different:

> Ese pobre muchacho no ha parado de llorar --> That poor guy hasn't
>   stopped crying. Clearly, pobre (poor) does not refer to the guy's wealth in this case.
>
> Ese muchacho pobre no ha parado de llorar --> Here, `pobre` is refering to
>   the guy's wealth - the guy is poor and hasn't stopped crying