# Noun and adjective word order and meaning of "atomic power engineering sites" in Spanish

Tags: traducción, gramática, orden-de-palabras

I am reading a product description and I want to translate it:

> The dosimeter may be used at atomic power engineering sites, physics laboratories, health care organizations as an electronic dosimeter for automated systems of personal dosimetry control ASPDC-21, and as an independent device.

I am trying the following:

> El dosímetro puede utilizarse en:  áreas ingenieriles con poder atómico, laboratorios de física, organizaciones de salud como un dosímetro electrónico para sistemas automatizados ASPDC-21 de control de dosimetría personal, y como un dispositivo independiente.

So, in English you have the adjective and then the substantive, but in Spanish you should switch the order, so besides the meaning of

> atomic power engineering sites

in Spanish, is it OK the order of the ideas when translated to Spanish? For example is it OK to translate the phrase:

> electronic dosimeter for automated systems of **personal dosimetry control ASPDC-21**.
>
> dosímetro electrónico para sistemas automatizados **ASPDC-21 de control de dosimetría personal**.

Note how they are switched.

Comment: A better translation of "atomic power" is "energía atómica".

Comment: This [question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/328/significance-of-adjective-placement/335#335) may bring you further answers to the question. And I'd personally advise putting the ASPDC-21 at the end of the sentence and in parentheses. Like this: [...] para sistemas automatizados blabla (ASPDC-21).

Comment: "energía atómica" ?   Que tal "energía nuclear" ?

Comment: laboratorios de física y organizaciones de salud ...y tambien como un dispositivo independiente. no?

Comment: I don't think that "power" and "energía" refer to the same concept.  Conceptually, power is energy per unit time.

Comment: Genial, very good! I'm physic, I agree with you... but: don't write potencia nuclear, or potencia atómica in place of atomic power. That will be a nation or organization with have the tecnology, speciely if militarity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La redacción original no es muy feliz. Aquí va un intento de traducción que no es literal.

> The dosimeter may be used at atomic power engineering sites, physics laboratories, health care organizations as an electronic dosimeter for automated systems of personal dosimetry control ASPDC-21, and as an independent device.

> El dosímetro puede utilizarse en plantas de energía atómica, en laboratorios de física, como  dosímetro electrónico para sistemas automatizados de control de dosimetría personal ASPDC-21 en organizaciones de salud y también como un dispositivo independiente.

**Edit**

Pero la verdad es que no parece redactado por un hispanohablante. Quizás alterando el orden y algunos términos resulte menos forzado:

> El dosímetro puede utilizarse en organizaciones de salud como dosímetro electrónico en sistemas automatizados de control de dosimetría personal ASPDC-21, en centrales nucleares, en laboratorios de física y como dispositivo independiente.