# Using or omitting "y" when there are several adjectives after noun

Tags: gramática

I am interested to know about situation when ALL adjectives are placed only after noun which they modify.

There is a sentence in this thread from SpanishDict https://www.spanishdict.com/answers/249899/question-regarding-a-sentence-with-two-adjectives-and-a-single-noun:

*Me gustó la comida hindú picante. = I liked the spicy Indian food.*

Questions:
1) When should "Y" be used to separate adjectives? My guess - when adjectives are of same group/importance (example - "*A big, beautiful, red flower.*" = "*Una flor grande, bonita y roja.*")

2) When several adjectives may be not separated by comma or "Y"? My guess - when they do not belong to the same category of adjectives describing noun visually (like in "spicy Indian food" example and UNlike in "flower" example above)

From other thread [Adjectives order when two or more adjectives modify one noun](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32007/23475) I have been given several examples, but there is one adjective before noun, so not sure if can be changed to the following:

"*un famoso cantante africano albino*" -> "*un cantante africano albino*" ??

"*los elaborados vestidos femeninos antiguos*" -> "*los vestidos femeninos antiguos*" ??

"*terribles erupciones volcánicas masivas*" -> "*erupciones volcánicas masivas*" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first reply in the thread you cited says,

> ... there are certain cases, like this one, when one adjective
>   describes the very nature/essence of the noun rather than to describe
>   a variant. No matter what, the food is "comida hindú" and basically
>   cannot be changed, but we can add another adjective that indicates a
>   variant which results in "comida hindú picante".

In terms of the [accepted answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32008/14627) to the other question, *hindú* in *comida hindú picante* is a **classifying** adjective. These stick close to the noun and also tend to form a unit of meaning with it. The other adjective(s), if any, go around that unit, either after or before.

In the examples with three adjectives you can leave out any of the three. There's some loss of meaning, of course, but the remainder of the phrase will be grammatical.

You use *y* between the adjectives when they belong roughly to the same category: classifying adjectives on the one hand, the rest on the other. The rule for same-category adjectives is actually the same as the rule for enumerations: it's item, comma, item, comma, ..., next-to-last item, *y*, last item:

- *el sombrero negro y alto*
- *una flor grande, bonita y roja*
- *leones feroces, indómitos, inmensos y rugientes*